# Implicit parameter and ClassTag

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

Can someone explain what the Scala compiler is trying to tell me with the error message below?

```
object Some {
  def apply[T: ClassTag](data: T)(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): T = data
}
object Other {
  def apply[T: ClassTag](data: T)(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): T =
    Some(data)(ordering.reverse)
}
```

Compiler says:

```
not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit evidence$2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T], implicit ordering: Ordering[T])T in object Some. Unspecified value parameter ordering.
```

The error arose when I added the `ClassTag` to the method in object `Some`, in order to use some internal arrays there. Initially, the code was (and compiled without errors):

```
object Some {
  def apply[T](data: T)(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): T = data
}
object Other {
  def apply[T: ClassTag](data: T)(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): T =
    Some(data)(ordering.reverse)
}
```

I know `ClassTag` adds an implicit with type information to overcome erasure, but I don't understand what that has to do with my ordering implicit parameters, or why the compiler suddenly thinks that ordering has no value...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This:

```
def apply[T: ClassTag](data: T)(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): T = data
```

is syntactic sugar for this:

```
def apply[T](data: T)(implicit evidence: ClassTag[T], ordering: Ordering[T]): T = data
```

When you explicitly specify the implicit parameters you must provide both of them. You can use `implicitly` to carry over the implicit `ClassTag`:

```
object Other { 
  def apply[T: ClassTag](data: T)(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): T =
    Some(data)(implicitly, ordering.reverse)
}
```

Comment: It's very clear but has a small mistake. We should use `implicitly[ClassTag[T]]` as there are more than one implicit parameters, we need to identify which one we want.

Comment: @cloud No, the parameters are distinguished by their order, the first parameter is the the ClassTag[T] and the second parameter the Ordering[T]. Because the type parameter can be inferred, a simple `implicitly` is sufficient.

Comment: Damn I forget the type inference...Thank you for your explanation, your answer is perfect!

Comment: The key piece of information is that you must either pass *all* implicit parameters or none of them. In my question I mentioned that *"I know `ClassTag` adds an implicit with type information to overcome erasure..."*, but I was unaware of the requirement to explicitly define either all, or none of the implicit parameters.