# In Scala, use a parameter implicitly, but do not pass it implicitly

Tags: scala

Suppose I want to explicitly pass an `ExecutionContext` as a parameter to a method, but want to use that context implicitly in the body of that method. I can achieve this with the following simple code snippet:

```
  def run(foo: Unit => Unit,
          ex1: ScheduledExecutorService) {
    import scala.concurrent.duration._
    implicit val ex2 = ex1
    scheduleAtFixedRate(foo, 1.seconds, 3.seconds) // pass ex2 implicitly, not explicitly
  }
```

Is there a way to do this without reassigning `ex1` to `ex2`, but still require the parameters to be *passed* explicitly?

Comment: Nope, and given how much syntax Scala already has, that's almost certainly a good thing. Your current approach is a fairly clear way to solve a not terribly common problem.

Comment: What they need is, in addition to implicitNotFound annotation, is implicitFound, which would emit a warning when a dangerous implicit value is used; then running -Xfatal-warnings would secure you against accidental usages. Soon you will be able to filter the benign usages of global context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you want to require that a parameter be passed in explicitly, the only way to use it implicitly within the body of the function is to reassign it to an implicit variable. Why you would ever want to do that defies my reasoning, however.

Comment: For example, you may have a method that needs an executor with particular characteristics that is different from the other executors (e.g., the method makes lots of blocking calls but the rest of the code is async/reactive). In such a case, you may want to force the caller to manually supply an executor so who ever is writing code that invokes the method has to think about which executor they are passing. However, inside the implementation, you may want to use that executor implicitly, for clarity of code.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution of implicit parameters is type-based. The only way I can think of (especially since you want to receive the parameter from the caller) is to have `run` accept the executor service implicitly, as in:

```
  def run(foo: Unit => Unit)(implicit ex1: ScheduledExecutorService) {
    // no need for the below; ex1 already used for implicit resolution
    // implicit val ex2 = ex1
  }
```

Of course, that means that the caller for the `run` method must define the implicit value to used for the executor service, or pass it explicitly as in:

```
run(someFoo)(someScheduledExecutorService)
```

Comment: One last thing: if you ever need to pass an explicit value when invoking a method that uses an implicit parameter, then please note that you have to supply ALL implicit parameters. Please see this question I asked for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718165/implicit-parameter-and-classtag

Comment: I took the comment in the snippet to mean that the "explicit passing" requirement was not for the caller of run, but for the method BEING called by run. Although I still think my understanding is what the poster meant, I may have missed the intent.In that light though, the question doesn't even make sense, unless you're trying to override an implicit in scope from your caller (in which case the curried syntax for providing the parameter in this answer helps)...