# What do Multiple parameter lists to Some() in scala achieve?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Can someone explain to me what the multiple parameter lists to Some() class below achieve?

I ran into this while reading a solution related to use of ClassTags in :

[Implicit parameter and ClassTag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718165/implicit-parameter-and-classtag)

```
object Other { 
  def apply[T: ClassTag](data: T)(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): T =
    Some(data)(implicitly, ordering.reverse)
}
```

Comment: what exactly you want to ask? Are you asking about type parameters T or what the question is not clear.

Comment: Per your update then everything is clear. That `Some` is not the the one of a **Option** but a new class that receives those two implicits on its second parameter list. So now, what is the question? There is nothing wrong with this code, it is simply passing the two implicit parameters explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

As the answer of the referenced question states, you can write `Some.apply` like this:

```
def apply[T](data: T)(implicit evidence: ClassTag[T], ordering: Ordering[T]): T = data
```

Or use `Context Bounds` for both (syntactic sugar), like:

```
def apply[T: ClassTag: Ordering](data: T): T = data
```

So in the `Other` it calls `Some.apply` with an explicit parameter (it changes the order).

As there is only **one** Parameter list allowed with implicit parameters, you have also to add the `ClassTag` parameter explicit.

You can achieve this with `implicitly`.

Check also the Documentation: [docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html)